# Getting iPhone addressbook contents without GUI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook, core-foundation

I would like to list all phone numbers (or any other field) of people in the addressbook.

I've written the following code:

```
- (void)addressBookFill{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    people = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    [addressBook release];
}

- (void)printAddressBook{
    for(id person in people){
        NSLog(@"%@", [person class]);
        NSLog(@"\t%@", person );
    }
}
```

When I invoke the printAddressBook method I get this on my console:

```
2010-07-06 10:34:11.998 app[91420:207] __NSCFType
2010-07-06 10:34:11.999 app[91420:207]  <CPRecord: 0x5d56ce0 ABPerson>
```

And I don't have any idea, how to dereference this ABPerson object, how to get any info from it.

I tried:

```
firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

but I got some exceptions.

Can anybody tell me how to get some info from these objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation about the ABPerson class:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABPerson_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and also the ABRecord class:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABRecord_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ABRecord

```
[ person valueForProperty: @"propName" ]
```

You can get the available properties with:

```
[ ABPerson properties ]
```

**[ EDIT ]**

On iPhone, you can use the following code to access a value:

```
NSString * lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue( person, kABPersonLastNameProperty );
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no thing as ABPerson Class on iPhone. There's only some ABPersonRef or ABRecord like here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html
and
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABRecordRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABRecordCopyValue

Answer (score 1):

May be this code will help you for iOS5, please like it

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray *arrayOfAllPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSUInteger peopleCounter = 0; 
    for (peopleCounter = 0;peopleCounter < [arrayOfAllPeople count]; peopleCounter++){
        ABRecordRef thisPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef) [arrayOfAllPeople objectAtIndex:peopleCounter];
        NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyCompositeName(thisPerson);
        NSLog(@"First Name = %@", name);  

        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);

        for (NSUInteger emailCounter = 0; emailCounter < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); emailCounter++){
            /* And then get the email address itself */ 
            NSString *email = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, emailCounter);
            NSLog(@"Email : %@",email);
        }
    } 
    CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want get only those contact who has email on my contact so use this code for iOS5

Please like it if it work

First add `AddressBook.framework` and `#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>`

```
 - (NSArray*)printAddressBook{
        NSMutableArray *mutableData = [NSMutableArray new];
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
        NSArray *arrayOfAllPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        NSUInteger peopleCounter = 0; 
        for (peopleCounter = 0;peopleCounter < [arrayOfAllPeople count]; peopleCounter++){
            ABRecordRef thisPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef) [arrayOfAllPeople objectAtIndex:peopleCounter];
            NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyCompositeName(thisPerson);
            NSLog(@"First Name = %@", name);  

            ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            for (NSUInteger emailCounter = 0; emailCounter < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); emailCounter++){
                /* And then get the email address itself */ 
                NSString *email = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, emailCounter);
                NSLog(@"Email : %@",email);
                NSMutableDictionary *personDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:name,@"name",email,@"email", nil];
                [mutableData addObject:personDict];
            }
        } 
        CFRelease(addressBook);
       return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableData];
    }
```